# UIToolbar and buttons not appearing (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I am trying to learn the nuts and bolts of using UIToolbar in iOS 7. To accomplish that, I  used the following pre-iOS 7 code:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-apps/using-toolbars-in-iphone/

The code works fine in iOS 6 but it seems that neither the toolbar nor its items are visible in iOS 7. Would you be so kind as to help me find a solution to the problem or point out resources that I could use to implement toolbars in iOS 7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly show the toolbar:

```
[self.navController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

Btw, setting the root view controller of the app should be done with `UIWindow`'s `setRootViewController:`, instead of just adding the view as a subview of the window.

So your code may look like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.rootViewController.title = @"Main View";
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];
    self.navController setToolbarHidden:NO];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

---

*This is purely a subjective opinion, but edumobile.org doesn't seems to be the best website out there to learn iOS/ObjC. These courses seems outdated / with bad practices and [WOT gave me a warning when entering](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/www.edumobile.org)... Nothing against them though, I didn't know this website before answering.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to check the code and providing me with a solution, @GuillaumeAlgis . As for websites that could help beginners like me with iOS/objective-c, which ones would you recommend?

Comment: I don't have a particular website in mind, but [Apple provides a lot of good (and up to date) tutorials and examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html).

Comment: Personally, apple's tutorials did not help me at first because they were too technical for a beginner. I recommend first following the Objective C tutorials at thenewboston.com, then reading some of the 300+ tutorials at raywenderlich.com